# How can I integrate and store sessions in my database, as opposed to storing them in a cookie and file system?

Tags: php, database

I've never worked with sessions in a database before, and I'm a little unclear on how they work. I have a user class already designed which stores user information: username, password, email etc. I also have a session class which uses the user ID to store a session cookie in the user's browser so that when they return to the application, a method is invoked to check if:

```
isset($_SESSION['id']){ $this->userId=$_SESSION['id']}
```

then take the user to the admin page. I've been reading that using the database is a more secure method of handling sessions, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this concept. So say I wanted to store the session info in the database, and have access to that info so that if the user clicked on a link to their profile page, for example, I could use the session info to get their user info. How could I achieve this? Does it even make sense to use this approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) are based on the session identifier, a string that uniquely identifies a browser session via a cookie<sup>1</sup> set on the client when `session_start()` is called. Since they are based on cookies, you should treat them as user input and you should never absolutely trust user input. Cookies can be stolen via [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), and PHP cookies are not encrypted by default.

Sessions are stored in the `%TEMP%` directory, whichever that may be for your system. The save location can be changed from the [session.save_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) directive or by the [session_save_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) during runtime, but on a typical hosting environment<sup>2</sup>, it's generally considered easier to gain access to the filesystem than a database.

The various security concerns are addressed on the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.security.php):

> The session module cannot guarantee that the information you store in a session is only viewed by the user who created the session.
>
> ...
>
> Assess the importance of the data carried by your sessions and deploy additional protections -- this usually comes at a price, reduced convenience for the user.
>
> ...
>
> The session module cannot guarantee that the information you store in a session is only viewed by the user who created the session.

[Session fixation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation) is the commonly quoted buzzword, you can find a little more info on the [Session Fixation Vulnerability in Web-based Applications](http://www.acros.si/papers/session_fixation.pdf) article that's referenced on the manual.

The [session_set_save_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) function allows you to  transparently choose where sessions are saved:

> session_set_save_handler() sets the user-level session storage functions which are used for storing and retrieving data associated with a session. This is most useful when a storage method other than those supplied by PHP sessions is preferred. i.e. Storing the session data in a local database.

After you build and set your handler, you can continue using sessions as usual. There are quite a few examples on the comments to the manual page on storing sessions to a database. Storing sessions in a database has an important disadvantage: if for any reason the database goes awol, then you've lost everything you've built around sessions too.

<sub><sup>1</sup> You can [propagate the session id via a URL parameter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php), but that's more trouble than it's worth.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> By typical I mean cheap shared hosting.</sub>